# Debounce directive for displaying the search result

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have a directive for searching for elements by title, now I'm trying to figure out how to make a directive for a delay, so that when I enter some text in the input field, the results are shown after 500ms

My debounce.directive.ts

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appDebounce]'
})
export class DebounceDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input('appDebounce') debounceTime = 500;
  private input = new Subject();
  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.input.pipe(debounceTime(this.debounceTime)).subscribe(event => this.clickEvent(event));
  }
  
  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    clickEvent(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.input.next(event);

  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

My search.component.html

```
<div id="search-component">
    <label class="search-label">Todo Search</label>
    <input class="search-input" placeholder="Search" appDebounce="500" [formControl]="searchValue" />
</div>
```

My search.component.ts

In this file, I have a debounceTime method in ngOnInit, but I need to get rid of it in favor of the directive

```
export class TodoSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  private searchTerm$ = new Subject<string>();
  private ngUnsubscribe$ = new Subject<void>();
  searchValue = new FormControl();

  constructor(private todoService: TodosService, private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.searchTerm$
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe$),
        debounceTime(500),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
      )
      .subscribe(term => {
        this.todoService.setSearchTerm(term);
        this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
      });
    this.searchValue.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
      this.searchTerm$.next(value);
    });
    this.searchValue.setValue('');
  }
```

But as long as it doesn't work, how do I solve it ?

Comment: Why @HostListener('click')? I assume you need to debounce keystrokes right?

Comment: @MikeOne Yes, you are probably right, but then, I probably need to call the pipe filter, or do I not think so?

Comment: Anyway - your approach is unlikely to work as the formControl (directive) doesn’t care about your directive. I think you probably will have to end up with a full, ControlValueAccessor component to be able to make this work. So something like a <debounce-input [time]=“500” [formControl]=“searchTerm” />

Comment: @MikeOne I'll try to figure it out, thanks, if nothing comes of it, then I'll try your option

Comment: @ZelarsGreen, if you're interested in another approach, take a look to this old (but fantastic) [Netanel Basal's article](https://netbasal.com/implement-ngmodeloptions-with-rxjs-and-custom-form-control-in-angular-4aa3bf96ab6). Take account that it's used rxjs 5, so you need translate to rxjs 6 but the idea it's great

Comment: Netanal always has good stuff. But as you said, that example needs quite some adaptations to make it work in a newer ng version.